# What do the [-], [+], [!] line prefixes mean in exploit outputs?

Tags: exploit, exploit-development

When you're using exploits, in the output, every line is prefixed with a symbol inside a set of square brackets.

For example:

```
[+] Set arguments.
[-] Running exploit.
[!] Warning server returned 404.
```

What are all the different ones and what do they all mean exactly?

Comment: they are simply ASCII icons for the type and level of log entries

Comment: The type and level is what I'm asking about. When is it appropriate to use X prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are simply ASCII icons for the type and level of log entries.

Many commandline programs do this, not just exploit code - it makes it easier to read the output.

I'm not sure that there is an established standard, but if you read the source code, you can see what decisions the devs made in their program.